# Protege: how to connect two classes with a data property

Tags: owl, protege

I am trying to implement an ontology in Protege. I have a class Murder and a class Person. The class Murder is connected to class Person by two object properties that are:

hasCriminal --> domain Murder, range Person

hasVictim --> domain Murder, range Person

I would like to express that class Murder needs to have a Victim who is dead. So i put a data property of Person named dead of type boolean (yes or no).
How can I say in class Murder that the data property "dead" of Person should be put true?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that. A data property is used to link an object (instance of a class) to a data value. You seem to think in terms of object orientation. I have written about how object orientation maps to ontologies [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/mathematical-formalization-of-object-orientation/).

Comment: Perhaps `ObjectProperty: hasVictim ¶ Range: Person that isDead value true` (in Manchester syntax). Do not forget to check *Reasoner > Configure > Individual Inferences > Data property assertions*.